# how to exactly remove a screen component in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

in the current top screen , I press a button which should pop the screen,
but `BEFORE the press event is post to JS thread`,
another screen is pushed to the nav stack,
so the pop operation is performed on the new coming screen,
it's wrong!!

but wait, why the press event in a below screen could produce if there's another one above it?
that's maybe the thread problem.
in JS thread the nav stack(a js object) has modified, but the real UIView change would wait until the call message reaching the UI thread. between this gap, the below screen had been pressed!

so, how could I ensure the pop should exactly pop itself??

btw, I have post the problem in theirs [issuse](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4694)